# jqGrid not POSTing to server with any data from inline edit

Tags: jquery, python, post, jqgrid, flask

So far really enjoying jqGrid, but still can't figure out how to POST data to the server when saving a cell after an inline edit. Tried many different configurations, and pored through documentation, but still can't crack it.

jqGrid is certainly making the call to the url I specify, but I don't see any day on the other side.

What's also curious is that, from my understanding, the call should pick up the url specified in the edit and save params if none exists in the jqGrid configuration, but that doesn't seem to be the case. When I remove editurl and cellurl from the config, the save errors as 'no url specified'.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the JS:

```
editParams = {
    "oneditfunc": null,
    "successfunc": null,
    "url": '/submit/adjustments',
    "extraparam": {
        UserAdj: function() {
            var sel_id = $('#rowed1').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            var value = $('#rowed1').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
            return 'test';
        },
        arg1 : 'test_it_out'
    },
    "aftersavefunc": null,
    "errorfunc": null,
    "afterrestorefunc": null,
}

saveparameters = {
    "successfunc" : null,
    "url" : 'submit/adjustments',
        "extraparam" : {
            UserAdj: function() {
            var sel_id = $('#rowed1').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            var value = $('#rowed1').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
            return 'test';
        }
        },
    "aftersavefunc" : null,
    "errorfunc": null,
    "afterrestorefunc" : null,
    "restoreAfterError" : true,
    "mtype" : "POST"
}

jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid({
    url: base_url + 'get/101/items',
    datatype: "json",
    jsonReader: {
        root: function (obj) { return obj.items; },
        id: 'id',
        page: function () { return 1; },
        total: function () { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.items.length; },
    },
    loadonce: true,
    colNames:['Vendor', 'Name', 'Price', 'Last Cost', 'Qty OH', 'Qty OO', 'Wks Selling', 'Str Velocity', 'Fleet Velocity', 'Reccomended Buy', 'User Adjustment'],
    colModel:[
        {name: 'vendor_name'},
        {name: 'name'},
        {name: 'price'},
        {name: 'cost'},
        {name: 'qty_OH', sorttype:'int'},
        {name: 'qty_OO', sorttype:'int'},
        {name: 'str_wks_selling', sorttype:'int'},
        {name: 'velocity', sorttype:'int'},
        {name: 'flt_five_wk_vel', sorttype: 'int'},
        {name: 'rec_buy', sorttype: 'int'},
        {name: 'user_adj_order', editable: true}
    ],
    onSelectRow: function(id){
         if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
            jQuery('#rowed1').restoreRow(lastSel); 
            jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel, saveparameters);
            lastSel=id; 
         }
       },
    ondblClickRow: function(id) {
        jQuery('#rowed1').jqGrid('editRow', id, true, editParams); 
    },
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#prowed1',
    sortname: 'name',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    autowidth: true,
    height: '100%',
    'cellEdit': true,
    'cellSubmit': 'remote',
    editurl: '/submit/adjustments',
    cellurl: '/submit/adjustments'
});
```

And the controller code:

```
@app.route('/submit/adjustments', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit_adjustments():
    print request.data
    print request.args
    return redirect(redirect_url())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some errors which I could find during reading:

- One can't combine cell editing and inline editing in one grid. It seems to me that your main problem is in the usage of `cellEdit: true` option. **You have to remove the option `cellEdit: true` to be able to use inline editing.**
- The line of `onSelectRow` with `saveRow` never works because the previous line contains `restoreRow`. So you first discard editing results and then try to save it.
- You specify `mtype : "POST"` only in `saveparameters`, but not in `editParams`. Because `saveRow` called directly not works in your code the option will not used. Fortunately `mtype : "POST"` is *default* option of inline editing. Nevertheless I would recommend you to define *one object* with all inline editing options and use it in all methods which you calls (`editRow`, `saveRow`, `restoreRow`).
- `UserAdj` function which you defined seems be strange because it uses `$('#rowed1').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id')`, but the grid contains no column with the name `_id`.
- I recommend you to use `gridview: true` option in all your jqGrids. It improves performance of the grid.
- Consider to use `autoencode: true` option of the grid. If you don't use it the input data will be interpreted as
- I recommend you to use `jQuery(this)` instead of `jQuery('#rowed1')` inside of all callbacks of jqGrid.
- You should don't forget to define variable `lastSel`.

Comment: Thanks, Oleg. Sounds like many small things. I'm now getting an error that says my 'editRow' and 'saveRow' functions are undefined, however I think all of my libraries are being loaded correctly. I'll start another question for that and come back to this to finish off the inline edit feature

Comment: Your answer is VERY PRECIOUS!

Comment: @luca76: I'm glad that the answer could help you too. You are welcome!